# Having issues migrating from an old table to a new one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I'm transferring data from one table to another.

The old table used to have a varchar column called City.

The new table instead of the name of the city, has an int column called CityId because I created a new table only for Cities.

My Cities table has the following columns:

```
CityID - PK

RegionID - FK

CityName - Varchar(50)
```

I'm running this Query to copy the old data for my new table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Client(EmailAddress, CityID)
a.EmailAddress, (SELECT CityID FROM Cities WHERE CityName collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = a.City)
FROM AdventureWorksOld.dbo.Client a
```

But I can't do that, because the subquery returns multiple rows:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

How can I fix my code so I can do something like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT CityName FROM Cities WHERE CityName = 'Oak Bay') -> Replace 'Oak Bay' with the text in the column
FROM AdventureWorksOld.dbo.Client
```

Thank you.

Comment: please post your Cities table

Comment: check your data in table `Cities`. It seems that there are multiple rows of `CityID` for a `City`

Comment: Run `SELECT CityName, COUNT(*) FROM Cities GROUP BY CityName` to find the records with duplicate city names. Delete one of the duplicates and try again.

Comment: Thank you, now I know why the query wasn't working, I had duplicated records

Answer (score -1):

probably this is what are you looking for ?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Client(EmailAddress, CityID)
SELECT 
    a.EmailAddress
,   c.CityID 
FROM AdventureWorksOld.dbo.Client a
LEFT JOIN Cities c ON c.CityName = a.City
```

Comment: This code will fail in the OP's environment because he apparently had duplicate values in his Cities Table.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Client(EmailAddress, CityID)
SELECT 
    a.EmailAddress
,   c.CityID 
FROM AdventureWorksOld.dbo.Client a
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 c.CityID FROM Cities c WHERE c.CityName = a.City) c
```

Comment: this query works but it does not resolve the root cause of the issue which is data issue

Comment: That is correct but it solves the issue the OP requested assistance with.@Squirrel. thanks for the down vote.

Comment: I down vote for 2 reasons. Firstly is the one that I have already mention. Second is a query / code without any explanation or description is not very helpful to others. If you can improve on the answer, i will be happy to retract the down vote

Comment: Well sometime you don't have the ability to make changes to a database and dinnertime you just need to get the job done but you have a great day @Squirrel